# "Save Configuration" in Drupal 7 Module not visible

Tags: 7

I inherited a customized Drupal 7 site and am trying to add some things without a lot of knowledge of how drupal works (I have general html/css/JS, and some classic ASP, .Net experience).  I was able to install a couple of modules (Widgets, Widgets Service Links, Widgets Services  - for Social Media buttons) but can't seem to enable them.  They have dependencies with each other, but they are all there.  I can click the check boxes but I see no where to save the enabling of the modules.  According to what I see out there, there should be a Save Configuration button, but it is not visible to me.  We have a couple of security updates that we haven't done, but when we did these previously they mucked up our configuration so we decided to hold off on them until we know what we're doing a bit more (we were able to restore from a backup).  Could the security update alerts be preventing the saving of modules?  That's the only thing I can think of other than our whole configuration being messed up somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your Drupal installation or one of the modules breaks the module scanner, have you checked your webserver logs? if so, what do they say?

You should definetly upgrade to the latest version of D7 before trying anything else.

If that doesn't solve the problem, it's most likely one of the 3:e party modules causing the issue, you'll have to manually disable them one by one to find out which one it is.

You can disable/enable modules using other methods than the module configuration page, i'd recommend a command-line utility called [Drush](http://drupal.org/project/drush). It's a very usefull tool for alot of Drupal related maintenance.

The other method would be to manually disable the modules directly in the database, [here's](http://drupal.org/node/157632) instructions on how to do that.

Comment: Actually, the Save Configuration Button, after further inspection, was hiding in a place that I wasn't expecting - right under the left menu in the modules page.  However, clicking it did not help me activate those modules.  I do think you are correct and we will need to completely overhaul our install at some point.  In the mean time I manually inserted the social links on our page...

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very much like a custom module is hiding the module save button to stop people adding/changing things. I've had the misfortune of inheriting sites with these sort of "security features" before too.

If you do have any custom modules installed. the simplest thing you can do to test is get Drush installed, run `drush dis CUSTOM_MODULE` and check to see if the button comes back. Then you'll know if it's the custom module's fault at least. You can also disable them manually in the `system` table but you should only do that if you *really* know what you're doing.

The upshot of that is you can also use Drush to install the other modules outside of the UI, so even if that's not the problem you'll still be able to install new modules.

Also, to find out if a change to core files is responsible for the problem, grab the [Hacked module](http://drupal.org/project/hacked) and run a report. If you install the Diff module along with it you'll get a side-by-side diff of exactly what has changed in core/contrib modules.

Comment: I haven't done this yet but I'm pretty sure we have custom modules installed - specifically a Vertical Tab Slider (that's a specific name but maybe also a general category of modules?).  I'm hopefully taking a couple of 2-day-long Drupal classes around here, and hopefully that will give me the push I need to start overhauling the site from the ground up.  We also "moved" it from a dev subdirectory, which I'm sure doesn't help matters!